# Linq Optional ORing (Method Syntax)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I combine these two methods into one?

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get { return a => a.Activity.Parent.ActivityUsers.Any(x => (x.User.Id == id)); }
}
```

and

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get { return a => a.Activity.ActivityUsers.Any(x => (x.User.Id == id)); }
}
```

notably, the idea is that I want to check the root record for links to a certain User. But, `a` may be a root or may be a child (one decendant/level only; not recursive). I want an ORing, so to speak, of these two Linq expressions.

Comment: I've updated my answer after further thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get 
  {
     return a => a.Activity.Parent.ActivityUsers
                  .Concat(a.Activity.ActivityUsers).Any(x => (x.User.Id == id));
  }
}
```

Or since you're only worried about a single level deep you could probably use:

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get 
  {
     return a => a.Activity.Parent.Any(a2 => 
         a2.ActivityUsers.Any(x => 
             (x.User.Id == id) || x.Activity.ActivityUsers.Any(y =>
                 y.User.Id == id)));
  }
}
```

This option is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override Expression<Func<Attachment, bool>> MatchingCriteria
{
  get { return a => a.Activity.Parent.ActivityUsers.Any(x => (x.User.Id == id)) 
                 || a.Activity.ActivityUsers.Any(x => (x.User.Id == id)); 
      }
}
```